# How can gRPC client know about network loss/failure?

Tags: java, stream, grpc, server-side

There is a server-side streaming in java project by using grpc. When the network was broken between server and client, the client doesn't even know about the problem, the streamobserver is idle and no activity. How can I know about this disconnection?

Comment: One way would be to have both sides sent "heartbeat" information every X seconds or so. When those stop coming in, you know that something isnt as it should be. Of course, it only tells you that no more heartbeats are coming in, not *why* that is.

Answer (score 1):

You do not know the connection broken until sending a message. That's [how TCP protocol works](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html).

So if you are in the middle of server-side streaming and suddenly unplugged your modem, the client side would never know until the OS closes the socket (may take minutes).

You could either change to implement bidi-streaming that the client sends requests periodically so it knows network failures when trying to write to the socket, or you can enable [keepAlive](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html#keepAliveTime-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).